# Как распознавать числа с плавающей точкой в тексте?

Tags: python, python-3.x

столкнулся с проблемой. Я делаю голосового ассистента и мне нужно распозновать числа с плавающей точкой в команде.

Текст у меня сохраняется в списке.
Например пользователь сказал: `"Пять целых шесть десятых"`. В коде сохраниться список:
`["пять", "целых", "шесть", "десятых"]`.

И вот это мне нужно перевести в вид: `5.6`.

Как это сделать я не понимаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а как вы из списка переводите текст в число? приведите свой код в вопросе.

Comment: Идете поиском по списку до "целых", каждое слово меняя на цифру. Потом запятая ставится, потом по списку до "десятых" аналогично. Если этого недостаточно для написания кода, то читайте внимательно учебник по языку - значит, знаний базовых не хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать библиотек `text2num`. Думаю там это предусмотрели. https://github.com/seriyps/ru_number_to_text

```
from text_to_num import text2num

def floatWrodrs(string):
    # Объеденям слова из списк
    s = ' '.join(string)

    # Передаем строку в библиотеку text2num
    num = text2num(s, "ru")

    # Получаем ответ 
    print (num)

floatWrodrs(["пять", "целых", "шесть", "десятых"])
```

Comment: Спасибо, но какая у вас версия text2num? Просто у меня выводит ошибку KeyError: "ru"

Comment: Кароче я установил с гит хаба эту библиотеку и всё заработало.